# Using Regex to check Name,10 digit Mobile number and a 12 digit number using ng-blur and match function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to validate these 3 mentioned above but I am  finding difficulty in using appropriate functions. ...please help.

The html code for 3 inputs

```
<input id="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="checkIfNameIsValid()"  placeholder="Name"></input>

<input id="mobile" ng-model="user.phone" ng-blur="checfIfMobileNumIsValid()" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10"></input>

<input id="Aerror" ng-model="user.aadhar"  ng-blur="checkIfAadharIsValid()"  placeholder="Aadhar Number" maxlength="12"></input>
```

the .js code

```
$scope.checfIfMobileNumIsValid = function()
{
    var mobile=/^\d{10}$/;
    if($scope.user.phone.match(mobile) || $scope.user.phone == '' || $scope.user.phone == 'null' || $scope.user.phone == null)  
    { 
        $scope.user.mobErrorMsg = 'Mobile number is not valid'; 
        $scope.error = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.user.mobErrorMsg = '';   
        $scope.error = false;
    }
}

$scope.checkIfNameIsValid = function()
{
    var name='/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/';
    if($scope.user.name.match(name)||$scope.user.name == ''||$scope.user.name=='null'||$scope.user.name==null)  
    {  
        $scope.user.NameErrorMsg = 'Name is not valid';
        $scope.error = true;
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $scope.user.NameErrorMsg = '';  
        $scope.error = false;
    }  
}

$scope.checkIfAadharIsValid = function()
{
    var aadhar='/^\d{12}$/';
    if($scope.user.aadhar.match(aadhar) || $scope.user.aadhar == '' || $scope.user.aadhar == 'null' || $scope.user.aadhar == null)  
    {  
        $scope.user.aadharErrorMsg = 'Aadhar is not valid';
        $scope.error = true;
    }   
    else
    {
        $scope.user.aadharErrorMsg = '';
        $scope.error = false;
    }

}
```

I am getting an error in browser console that cannot read property 'match' of undefined..please help.

Comment: First, to validate, you should use `regex.test(string)` instead of `string.match(regex)`. Second, for mobile number, try `/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/`

Comment: can u please give the code by using the above given data..Its still taking aalphabets in the place of numbers a error is not showing

Comment: check out my http://plnkr.co/edit/rzruP5Dznpipz0Xpe8X5?p=info Registration form in which I have handled the password in regex and messages. Hope it helps

Comment: You are missing error labels. https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/t2n0Lswj/

Comment: your fiddle explained well ...I got just what i needed...Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using ng-messages in angular?

Here's the example code of using ng-messages for a valid e-mail:

```
<div>
         <label>User Email</label>
        <div>
           <input  type="text" placeholder="paul@lebensraum.com" ng-model="user.email" name="userMail" required ng-pattern="/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/">
       </div>
       <div ng-messages="user.userMail.$error" class="error" role="alert" ng-if="user.userMail.$dirty">
        <div ng-message="required" style="margin-left: -13%;">Please User Email ID</div>
        <div ng-message="pattern" style="margin-left: -13%;">Please Enter A Valid Email Id</div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: happy to help.. :)